# Accessing &str as &[u8]

Tags: tcp, rust

I'm driving myself bonkers with this one, because judging by the documentation it should be painless: how do I cast a string into an `&[u8]` so I can send it over the wire via TCP or UDP? The `bytes!()` macro only appears to work on literals directly.

Here's the skeleton for a TCP app, cribbed entirely from other sources. Right now it works as an echo server. The stumbling block I'm having is figuring out how to print the &[u8] as a string on the terminal, or how to cast strings from `io::stdin().read_line()` into &[u8] to send over the wire, chat-style.

This fails to compile on a `` error: mismatched types: expected `&[u8]` but found `&str` (expected vector but found &str) ``:

```
fn run_tcp_test_server(listen_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let mut acceptor = TcpListener::bind(listen_addr).listen().unwrap();
    println("[ INFO ] listener is ready.");

    loop {
        let stream = Cell::new(acceptor.accept().unwrap());
        do spawn {
            println("[ INFO ] got a request.");

            let mut stream = stream.take();

            let mut my_read_buff = ~[0, ..1024];
            match stream.read(my_read_buff) {
                Some(n) => {
                    stream.write(my_read_buff.slice_to(n));
                },
                _ => ()
            }

            let out_msg = "Hello World\r\n";
            stream.write(out_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I also don't think the `let mut my_read_buff = ~[0, ..1024]` can possibly be right, that seems like a C-style overflow waiting to happen, which I thought Rust was supposed to fix.

I'm pretty confused by this, my understanding is that `&str` is `&[u8]` and I'm getting snagged by the type system, but can't get past this. I've tried to implement some of the functions from the `std::str::raw` in unsafe blocks but had no luck there, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&str` has the same representation as `&[u8]`, but it has an additional invariant: the contents is always valid UTF-8, hence it is not the same type, i.e. you have to explicitly "cast" between them (a little similar to `u8` and `i8` having the same representation but requiring an explicit cast to use them in place). This "cast" is done with [`.as_bytes()`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.as_bytes) to go from `&str` → `&[u8]`, and [`std::str::from_utf8`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) for the other direction (on 0.8, the reverse cast is `from_utf8_slice` FWIW). The `&str` → `&[u8]` cast is very, very cheap; with optimisations on it is literally zero-cost (the other direction has to check for valid UTF-8, and hence is O(n)), and with them off it is still a function call to a function with a very small number of instructions.

Hence, you need:

```
stream.write(out_msg.as_bytes());
```

(If `out_msg` is always the same message you can actually use the `b` prefix to get a compile-time byte literal:

```
stream.write(b"Hello World\r\n")
```

)

---

> I also don't think the let mut my_read_buff = ~[0, ..1024] can possibly be right, that seems like a C-style overflow waiting to happen, which I thought Rust was supposed to fix.

No, vectors and slices have their length stored in them so the `.read` call knows how much space it is allowed to fill, and won't/can't write beyond the end of it.

(FWIW, if your buffer is always a fixed length, you can drop the `~`, i.e. `let mut my_read_buff = [0, ..1024];`, so `my_read_buf` will have type `[u8, .. 1024]`, i.e. a fixed length vector of 1024 `u8`'s. This avoids the heap allocation.)

Comment: `.read()` returns `Option<uint>`: for `Some(n)`, `n` will never be longer than the length of the vector you're reading into.